# How to plot a polar plot?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, polar-coordinates

the question 
Given N=1, an antenna has a radiation pattern given as y(theta)=sin(N4pitheta)/(N4pitheta) Assume that the formula is valid over the range of  .  Generate a polar plot of the radiation pattern. Use 400 points for your graph.

here is my code, I keep getting "THETA and RHO must be the same size." what does this mean and how can I fix my cod? thanks

```
   function [graph,x,y]=question3(N)
      x=linspace(-pi,pi,400);
      y=(sin(N*4*pi*x)/(N*4*pi*x));
      graph='polar(x,y)';
    end
```

Comment: That code does not give that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are performing matrix division, not elementwise division.

change `y=(sin(N*4*pi*x)/(N*4*pi*x))` to `y=(sin(N*4*pi*x)./(N*4*pi*x))`

Note that in Matlab, `*` and `/` will perform matrix operations while `.*` and `./` will perform array operations.

[Read more here.](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html?refresh=true)

---

Side note: It looks like you are using `eval` to evaluate the output of that function. If it is your profesor who did this, leave it, but remember that [even Matlab staff themselves suggest never to use eval.](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/)